# Gum excreting from mango fruits

Tags: diseases, mango

I just found that some gum is excreting from the fruits of mango. Here are the pics. Could someone tell me what it is? How to cure it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The gum seems to be on cut/damaged part of the skin.  Are they bruises or insect infestation ?

Comment: Looks like some infestation. But its only to two fruits which are touching/closer to the painted wood block. Currently others are fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think they are bruised by rubbing against the fence.  If you can actually spot any insects on them, then try spraying Neem oil.